# Shared and Per-Tenant Tables in Same Database

Tags: database-design, multi-tenant

**Short Version**:

Is it ok to have some shared tables, and other per-tenant tables in the same database?

**Longer Version:**

We (me and some non-stackoverflow-ers) are designing some multitenant SAAS.

We are currently using a shared database and shared schema architecture, with each table having a tenant_id column to differentiate between tenants' data.
With small data sets, like in our 'users' table (If we have 1000 tenants, each with 10 users, = 10,000 rows), this works just fine.

However, there are some tables that will become extremely large. For example, 'files' table. Each tenant may have a million files whose metadata needs to be stored in the database. Each tenant having 1,000,000 files creates a 1bn line table.
My worry is that this will be slow to manipulate, and I want to chop up the files table by tenant.

**Questions:**

1. Is it acceptable / advisable to have some shared tables, and other per-tenant
   tables, eg `files_<tenant_id>`?

   I would like a critique regarding things such as scalability, backup, maintainabiltiy.
2. What are the other options for handling such large data.
3. Is this still considered a shared schema?

Comment: Must you save files in a table? Is there no way you can put them in a local folder by the tenant/user? It will be a bit easier process

Comment: @BhrugeshPatel The files will be stored in the filesystem. Just metadata for each file, such as id, path, permissions etc will be stored in the database.

Comment: Even if you say break them by tenants, you cant go creating new table for each tenant. If you split them by file type, searching will be a pain. Although I highly doubt that there will be 1bn lines in your table. But if you must break them then probably go by last name set.. i.e. for A-H in table 1, I-S in table 2 & rest in table 3 or something like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Which db? Do you mean database the way MySQL means database or schema?

Really, a tenant is gonna have 1M files? It will be easier to split them up w tenant-per-db

We have tenant_id style system and if I were to do it again, I'd go with one tenant per schema.